# How to change my Website direction LTR to RTL with CSS

Tags: css

I have a website [urdu.gvnews.live](http://urdu.gvnews.live) i want to flip the direction from Ltr to rtl please help me how can i change it.
the css link is http://gvnews.live/urdu/css/style1.css

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is something you are looking for

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/reversing-text/

Go through it and try changing.